# How do I read formatted data with typos?

Tags: c++, string, fstream

There are already several threads out there that deal with reading formatted strings, but my problem is that my text file have occasional typos. Here is an example of what most of my strings looks like:

```
Par(custom)1929;
```

The problem I am having is that some of the strings look like this:

```
Par({custom)1929:
```

I'm wondering how I can identify strings that don't follow the correct format and I will throw an error. I just can't find a solid way searching the string and finding the typos.

EDIT:

Here is sample code of what I'm using with no typos in the strings. This will get the middle word "custom" if there are no typos in the string. word is the string. com.fi is a data element where I'm storing the info.

```
int left = word.find("(");
int right = word.find(")");
com.fi = word.substr(left+1,right - lbraq - 1);
```

Comment: Simple: If you have a format you're trying to validate you need a parser that understands that format.

Comment: It helps to post any code that you've already tried.

Comment: @tadman Do you have link or something I can reference to gain more knowledge on parser for strings. Anything would help.

Comment: @nwalton I added sample code of what I want to do. It's the retrieve to information, but I don't have anything to check if those brackets are/aren't there. I just assume they are.

Comment: Put lots of strict format checking in the parser and report any bad lines to a separate file. Give that file to the intern to fix.

Comment: You need to be able to precisely express the legal formats.

Comment: @Galik lol and Thanks.

Comment: @PLayers4U: after you extract `com.fi`, it is pretty easy to check if its first character is `'{'` or not. As for the extraction, consider this: `int left = word.find("(") + 1; int right = word.find(")", left); com.fi = word.substr(left, right - left);` Then you can remove undesirable characters from `com.fi` as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Are your formatted strings on separate lines or have some uniform spacing between them? If so, you can use a combination of `std::ifstream` and the C++ regex library, as seen here:

```
std::ifstream inf(...); // filename
const std::regex rgx("Par\\(\\w+\\)[0-9]{4}");
std::string read;
while (std::getline(inf, read)) {
    if (!std::regex_match(read, rgx)) { /* error handling here */ }
}
```

The double backslashes prevent the compiler from reading the escaped regex characters as *actual* escaped characters, while w means words, like digits and letters, and plus means match one or more of word characters. The brackets with the range inside of them are a capture group that capture certain characters you specify within them, in this case being any numeric character. The curly brackets following the capture group specify within them how much of that group we want to match, in this case being four characters. I escaped the parenthesis because they are significant to regex matching.

If the format I used here didn't match yours, C++ uses a regex syntax that is heavily based off of JavaScript's, and there are several sites you can use to test JavaScript regex, like regex101.com.